# Spring Security applies filter to all paths, not only "/api**"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am struggling to get my Spring Security config done properly.
I have JWT security set up, but I want it to work only on `/api**` and I can't get it right... Even when I try to hit `localhost:8080` I am getting error from JWTFilter.

This is my config:

```
public static final String TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT = "/api/**";
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(this.restAuthEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(FORM_BASED_REGISTRATION_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll()
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT).authenticated()
                    .and()
                .addFilterBefore(buildJWTLoginFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(buildJWTAuthFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Theoretically it should apply filters only on API, but it somehow applies them on all paths.

Can someone help to make it working as it should work, so only `/api**` will be secured and I can freely access all paths outside `/api` ?

Comment: .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll() may be you should precise the allowed HttpMethod

Comment: What? You just copied one line of my code... Login and registration are working properly

Comment: Why do you think, your configuration should only work for `/api**`? You didn't restrict it. Your configuration works for `/**` by default. Why do you think your filter should work only for `/api**`? Show the code of your filter, I guess you didn't implement the restriction.

Answer (score -1):

Add `and().antMatchers("/**").permitAll()`